# simple javascript: search url for string, do something

Tags: javascript

I just need a simple function that will search the current url for a string (ie "nature") and then will add a class to an object. I keep finding ways to search the query, but I want to search the entire url. If possible, without jQuery. If not, jQuery will work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get the URL with `window.location.href`, and search it however you like:

```
var location = window.location.href;
if(location.indexOf("whatever") > -1) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

[`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location) returns a `Location` object, which has a property `href` containing the entire URL of the page.

Answer (score 3):

The most basic approach is something like this:

```
window.location.href.indexOf('nature')
```

That will return `-1` if the string is not found. Otherwise, it returns the index of the string inside the URL string.

Answer (score 1):

Using regexes, as an alternative:

```
if (window.location.toString().match(/nature/)) {
    yourobj.className = 'newclass';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're searching for a value in the QueryString, you can try this:

```
var searchIndex = window.location.search.indexOf("nature");
```

Otherwise, you can do this:

```
var searchIndex = window.location.href.indexOf("nature");
```

You can also do this:

```
var searchIndex = window.location.href.search("/nature/");
```

To check whether the word was found, you can do this:

```
if (searchIndex > -1)
    //logic here
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this one should give you a good starting point. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NUsP6/1) is available here.

```
<div id="test">Some text</div>
```

---

```
.red
{
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

---

```
function handler( url, textToMatch, objectToChange, classToAssign )
{
   if (url.search(textToMatch) != -1)
   {
       objectToChange.className = classToAssign;
   }
}

var url = 'http://www.some-place.com&nature'; //window.location.href in your case
var div = document.getElementById('test');

handler(url, 'nature', div, 'red');
```

Answer (score 0):

The hash in the URL caused issues for me, so instead I used a "?".

As an example lets say I have the URL: http://example.com?someString

First I retrieved the URL:

```
var activeURL = window.location.href;
```

Then I take everything from the index of "?" + 1(because I do not care to include "?") onward.

```
var activeItem = aactiveURL.substring(activeUrl.indexOf('?') + 1, activeURL.length);
```

activeItem will be "someString"