# How to remove a sidebar for certain URLs?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a site that displays training courses - each training course uses the same page template which has a sidebar advertising the dates the training is running. I wish to remove this sidebar from 2 of my courses, but not from any of the others.

Each course has an ID which appears in the URL, so I have been attempting to filter via this.

```
if(window.location.indexOf("2"))
{
  $('#course-sidebar').hide();

}
```

This does not cause any errors, but also does not hide the sidebar for course 2.

Comment: Why have you tagged as Php?

Comment: `window.location.href.indexOf('foo')` https://stackoverflow.com/a/7558749/3392762

Comment: @progrock Because I thought there would probably be a php alternative to solve this issue.

Comment: You can use strpos on `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and check for a non-false result in Php, in a similar manner.  But the digit 2 may occur in many URLs and give you false positives.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is better to be done in the php.

In the page where you have the side bar add a if condition to check if the urlsegment=2.

First get the desired url segment to be checked

```
<?php $uriSegments = explode("/", parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));

if($uriSegments[3] !=2 && $uriSegments[3] !=x) { ?>
<sidebar>
--Html code for sidebar--

</sidebar>
<?php } ?>
```

so the sidebar html code will be visible only when the id is not equals to your desired course id